# Extract Array Elements from an Array assigned to a Key of a Map Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added an Array of 2 dates to a Key of a new Map object. I want to access these individual dates and store them in columns 3 & 16 of another sheet viz `ShtStudy`. Here is a snippet of the code:

ShtFC:

```
ID    | Name | Sol  | Own  | Acct  | Date1      | Date2      |
10000 | abc  | sol1 | own1 | acct1 | 09/01/2020 | 10/02/2020 |
10003 | def  | sol3 | own3 | acct3 | 01/05/2020 | 03/10/2020 |
```

ShtStudy:

```
Name  |  ID  |  Date1     | Sol  | Col.... | Col 15 | Date2      | .... |
abc   |10001 | 09/01/2020 | sol1 | .....   | .....  | 10/02/2020 | .... |
def   |10003 | 01/05/2020 | sol3 | .....   | .....  | 03/10/2020 | .... |
```

Code Snippet:

```
r_Study = FindLastRow(shtStudy);
r_FC = FindLastRow(shtFC);
let StudyRng = shtStudy.getRange(2, 1, r_Study - 2 + 1, c_Study);
let FCRng = shtFC.getRange(2, 1, r_FC - 2 + 1, 7).getValues();

const idMap = FCRng.reduce( (mp, [id,,,,,date,date1]) => mp.set(id, [date, date1]), new Map );
const SRng = StudyRng; //shtStudy.getDataRange();
const svalues = SRng.getValues();
svalues.forEach(row => {
  console.log(idMap.get(row[1])[0]);  //===> This does not work
  console.log(idMap.get(row[1])[1]);  //===> This does not work

  row[2]  = idMap.get(row[1])[0] || row[2];
  row[15] = idMap.get(row[1])[1] || row[15];
});
SRng.setValues(svalues);
```

I tried using `Slice` method also to access the individual dates in the array, but does not seem to work.

```
idMap.get(row[1]).slice(0)
idMap.get(row[1]).slice(1)
```

If i just use the below line, i get to see the Array with the 2 dates:

```
idMap.get(row[1])
```

**Output:**

```
[ Wed Aug 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  Thu Sep 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) ]
```

[image: idMap object]

Comment: please add data in text from to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz i have added sample data tables showing FCSht Dates viz., Date1 & Date2 that i need to transfer to StudySht in the appropriate columns. Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: I tried to explain my question very clearly i.e. to extract each date stored in the Array that was assigned to a Key (ID) of a Map Object. I want to extract and place these dates in the other sheet in columns 3 & 16 as depicted from the data tables.

Comment: @TheMaster this is the same code that you shared, except that i have made the `value` part of Map object into an Array to include another Date2 to also transfer to the other sheet.

Comment: It seems quite likely that you have `id` values in the second sheet that do not have a match in the first. Make sure to inspect the *actual* value that `.get()` returns when the error occurs. The thing is that it will work for some rows, but not for others, so you need the right debugging information.

Comment: Yes it is matching the `id` in StudySht and based on `id` key it is transfering the Array to both the 3 & 16 columns. The only problem is that i am not able to extract the individual date values from the Array and transfer those to the respective columns. `Bracket []` notation viz., `[0]` & `[1]` does not seem to get me the values.

Comment: yes @trincot it returns `undefined` for some and for others it returns the date array as shown in the `Output`. I think i just need a line of code to extract the values from the array returned by `idMap.get(row[1])`.

Comment: What do you mean by `but does not seem to work.` What does it do? Do you get an error? Or nothing? Please elaborate.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, when i run in debug mode, the debugger exits on encountering  `idMap.get(row[1]).slice(0)
idMap.get(row[1]).slice(1)` and i dont get any console logs.

Comment: What happens if you run it *not* in debug mode?

Comment: if i run the code with `row[2] = idMap.get(row[1]) || row[2]; row[15] = idMap.get(row[1]) || row[15];` it does not update the columns but runs without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases the expression `idMap.get(row[1])` will be undefined. This happens when an id in the second table does not match with one in the first. And when it is undefined, you cannot append [0] to that expression.

There is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator you can use for that case:

```
row[2]  = idMap.get(row[1]).?[0] || row[2];
```

If you have no support for that operator, then:

```
let match = idMap.get(row[1]);
row[2]  = match ? match[0] : row[2];
```

You should of course do the same thing for the assignment to `row[15]`.

Comment: the former one is not supported. When i copy the latter ones, it triggers an error and ";" on 2nd line is highlighted. `let match = idMap.get(row[1]);
===> error on this 2nd line row[2]  = match ? match[0] || row[2]; row[15]  = match ? match[1] || row[15];`

Comment: `5:07:23 PM Error Attempted to execute xxxxxxx, but could not save.`

Comment: i think it is missing syntax ":"....should i replace the "||" instead with a ":" ?

Comment: Yes, indeed that should be a ":" of course (ternary operator)